# Cannot commit with context menu in TortoiseSVN and has no Settings for Git

Tags: git, tortoisesvn, contextmenu, commit

I recently reinstalled Windows 7 and my new Git & TortoiseSVN doesn't seem to work as I expect them. I need to commit from the context menu. However the option is not there. I tried to check the Tortoise settings but Git is not in there.

I am noob at this so sorry for the dumb question but what seems to be the problem?

Context Menu Image: [No Commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3ywM.png)

Tortoise Settings Image: [No Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DJZ3.png)

Comment: Can you tell us which IDE/tool you are using?

Comment: The repositories are located in bitbucket. I am working on my projects using XAMPP server, Notepad++ and currently committing manually using git bash. 

All the software that I use is up to date as I downloaded everything from the original sources and only the latest versions.

Comment: It is strange that the bash is still running but you can't use Git.

Comment: I have committed and pulled several times using console:

git clone project
git pull origin master


All work fine. But context menu doesn't work for some reason.. I have to type git add. git commit -m message git checkout -b branch etc - everything manually